# How to select lines and print in a list python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
1 f
2 f
3 f
4 g
5 g
6 g
```

and I want to print out the first two lines of `f` and `g`, as:

```
1 f
2 f
4 g
5 g
```

any idea how to approach this?

Comment: A python list cannot look like _that_. A list must have at least a pair of brackets. Please include the actual list in Python syntax, not a printout. Also, what did you try to solve the problem yourself? Include your code and explain what went wrong.

Comment: Also address some corner cases: what if there is only one "g" item? is the letter column guarenteed to be sorted in order or can you get four 'g's followed by, say, two 'b's?

Answer (score 0):

You could to consider grouping your list.  An example:

```
l = [['1', 'f'], ['2', 'f'], ['3', 'f'], ['4', 'g'], ['5', 'g'], ['6', 'g']]
```

To group the list, use a key. In this case, the key would be the second value of each list item, so `x[1]`:

```
from itertools import groupby
for _, g in groupby(l, lambda x: x[1]):
    print(list(g)[:2])
```

Slice each group, to only print the first two items, `list(g)[:2]`.

Output:

```
[['1', 'f'], ['2', 'f']]
[['4', 'g'], ['5', 'g']]
```

Note: this is similar to `uniq` in the shell. And it depends or the key values being sorted. You might have to sort the data before using this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Have added a list of dict, with elem to print along with a count key
Simply increment the value of count to make sure no more than max_limit elements are print.

```
myList = ['1 f', '2 f', '3 f', '4 g', '5 g', '6 g']
elems_to_print = [{'elem': 'f', 'count': 0}, {'elem': 'g', 'count': 0}]
max_limit = 2

for myL in myList:
    for elem in elems_to_print:
        if elem['elem'] in myL and elem['count'] < max_limit:
            #Elem found
            elem['count'] += 1
            print("%s"%(myL))
```

Comment: Since SO is not a code writing service, users are discouraged from posting solutions to the questions that do not demonstrate at least some research and effort.